# Data structures suitable for searching

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, search

I have common problem. I have some data and I want search in them. My issue is, that I dont know a proper data structures and algorhitm suitable for this situation.

There are two kind of objects - `Process` and `Package`. Both have some properties, but they are only data structures (dont have any methods). Next, there are PackageManager and something what can be called ProcessManager, which both have function returning list of files that belongs to some `Package` or files that is used by some `Process`.

So semantically, we can imagine these data as

#### Packages:

- Package_1

  - file_1
    _ file_2
  - file_3
- Package_2

  - file_4
  - file_5
  - file_6

Actually file that belongs to Package_k can *not* belong to Package_l for k != l  :-)

#### Processes:

- Process_1

  - file_2
  - file_3
- Process_2

  - file_1

Files used by processes corresponds to files owned by packages. Also, there the rule doesn't applies on this as for packages - that means, `n` processes can use one same file at the same time.

Now what is the task. I need to find some match between processes and packages - for given list of packages, I need to find list of processes which uses any of files owned by packages.

My temporary solution was making list of `[package_name, package_files]` and list of `[process_name, process_files]` and for every file from every package I was searching through every file of every process searching for match, but of course it could be only temporary solution vzhledem to horrible time complexity (even when I sort the files and use binary search to it).

What you can recommend me for this kind of searching please?
(I am coding it in python)

Comment: Infinitely deep or only two level as your example? i.e., could you have `Package_1/sub_package/sp_file_1`?

Comment: Only two level as in example

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of what you are trying to do - given a file name, you want to find a list of all the processes that use that file, this snippet of code should help:

```
from collections import defaultdict 

# First make a dictionary that contains a file, and all processes it is a member of.
file_process_map=defaultdict(list)
[file_process_map[fn].append(p) for p in processes for fn in p.file_list]
```

Basically, we're converting your existing structure (where a process has one or more files) into a structure where we have a filename, and a list of processes that use it.

Now when you have a file you need to search for (in the processes) just look it up in the "file_process_map" dictionary and you'll have a list of all the processes that use the given file.

It is assumed here that "processes" is a list of objects, and each object has a file_list attribute that contains a list of associated files.  Obviously, depending on your data structure you might need to alter the code..

Comment: You meant to write `[file_process_map[fn].append(p) ...` I think.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That will have O(n^2) time complexity, or not?

Comment: yep Lukas - i've fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the matching with sets should be faster:

```
watched_packages = [Package_1, Package_3]   # Packages to consider

watched_files = {    # set comprehension
    file_
    for package in watched_packages
    for file_ in package.list_of_files
}

watched_processes = [
    process
    for process in all_processes
    if any(
        file_ in watched_files
        for file_ in process.list_of_files
    )
]
```